# I cloned an Ubuntu 20.04 installation onto a separate drive and the cloned copy seems to have a broken package manager, how do I fix this?

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to install any package using apt, it gives this error:

```
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extract templates from packages: 26%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extract templates from packages: 53%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extract templates from packages: 79%E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
Extract templates from packages: 100%
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 0:
 end of file after field name ''
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

attempting to run apt update fails with this error:

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/dpkg/status (1)
W: To correct these problems, you may want to run apt update
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

running 'head -n5 /var/lib/dpkg/status' outputs a blank line

running 'ls -al /var/lib/dpkg/status' outputs '-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1516491 Jul 11 19:14 /var/lib/dpkg/status'

I have a lot of packages installed and files on this install, so doing a fresh install isn't really an option.

Comment: Please add output of `head -n5 /var/lib/dpkg/status`, `ls -al /var/lib/dpkg/status` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1258513/edit).